# VMware Tools Installer Does Not Run

Tags: vmware-tools

The Host System is Windows 10 with MS Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) installed (v14.29.30135).  The Guest OS is Ubuntu Linux 22.04.  The Oracle VM VirtualBox is version 6.1.34 with VBox Guest Additions v6.1.34 and Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.34.vbox-extpack installed.  Hardware is laptop x64 machine.

I am stuck trying to install VMware-tools-windows-12.0.5-19716617.  The installer setup64.exe seems to start to run but then quickly stops running without any error messages.  I have tried two separate methods (independent download of.exe file, same .exe file from cdrom .iso image), results same.  I do not understand why vmware tools setup64.exe installer is failing to run.  Please advise how to fix.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Tools are to be installed on the guest Ubuntu Linux OS not on the Host.

For Linux guests, these days most distros would install open source vm tools automatically when the VM is created.

Inside Ubuntu Linux Guest OS use something like:
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop

The original post question had a confusion.  VMware and Oracle VM are produced by two different companies.  The VBox Guest Additions are installed from the Windows Host OS but the Open VM Tools are not.